# How do I access each node from a JSON Array (Not JSON Object)?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I need to download data from a URL which has a JSON Array, not JSON object, at least that is what my understanding is.

Retrieving DATA from URL:

```
// JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(ParsingDta);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Employee");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    // JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = jsonObject1.getString("id").toString();
    String name = jsonObject1.getString("name").toString();
    String salary = jsonObject1.getString("salary").toString();
    database.insertData(id, name, salary);
    str += "\n Employee" + i + "\n name:" + name + "\n id:" + id + "\n salary:" + salary + "\n";
    // textView1.setText(str);
}
```

The above has JSON Object I guess and I need JSON array

```
[{"billedret":0,"class":"com.enteleki.sfa.botree.RetailerSummary","ctgcode":"G00"  ...
```

and so on..

Comment: Could you add a little bit more of your JSON file?, I can't see Employee tag

Comment: Employee is based on JSONObject ,i do not want that..I want to use JSONParsing for the data posted at last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to get data from the URL

```
public void printRes(String res) throws JSONException { 
    try {
        //the asyncTask returns string to this function

        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(res);
        int t = arr.length();
        nameArray = new String[t];
        distArray = new String[t];
        latArray = new String[t];
        lonArray = new String[t];
        pgr.setProgress(70);
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            pgr.setProgress(50);
            nameArray[i] = (arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
            distArray[i] = (arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("distance"));
            latArray[i] = (arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude"));
            lonArray[i] = (arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude"));


        }
```

EDIT

I used an asyncTask To download data from the url

```
        String latt = LatVal.getText().toString();
        String lonn = LongVal.getText().toString();

        // Create data variable for sending values to server

        data = URLEncoder.encode("lat", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(latt, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("longi", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(lonn, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("radius", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(Dis, "UTF-8");

        text = "";


        // Send data

        new AsyncCaller().execute(data);
```

This string is send as a POST in the thread AsyncCaller

```
class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{

 MainActivity obj=new MainActivity();
 BufferedReader reader=null;
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
 super.onPreExecute();

  //this method will be running on UI thread

 }
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String...res) {

//this method will be running on background thread so don't update UI      
//  frome here
//do your long running http tasks here,you dont want to pass argument 
//and u can access the parent class' variable url over here
//String ads=Arrays.toString(res);

try {
  //Create connection

    // Defined URL  where to send data
    URL url = new URL("**your URL**");

 // Send POST data request
 String data=res[0];
//String sub="lat=10.0243567&longi=76.3084289&radius=500";
//"lat=ben&longi=ascd&radius=500";
  URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
  conn.setDoOutput(true); 
  OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
  wr.write(data); 
  wr.flush(); 

  // Get the server response 
  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  String line = null;

  // Read Server Response
  while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      {
             // Append server response in string
             sb.append(line + "\n");

      }

 obj.text = sb.toString();

  } catch(Exception ex)
  {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
   finally
  {
   try
   {

      reader.close();
   }

   catch(Exception ex) {}
 }

 // Show response on activity

return obj.text;
 }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);

try {
obj.printRes(result);//this contains the download data from the URL
} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

}


}
```

I used this code to download data from a url while posting some longitude and latitudes......

U can make the desired changes to download your data,..

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot..Could you help me with downloading the data from the link ?? i'm kinda new to all this.. :/

Comment: @Venky please check my edited code...I added a thread to retrieve the Data from url

Comment: Ah thanks a lot,much appreciated,i made another class called download_data.java to make it work.Now i need to pass these values to a SQLite database

Comment: I'm really confused here,which one is the Main Activity and which belongs to a separate Class ?? I'm new to this..so sorry if i'm naive..Like can you tell me which of the above code quotes belong where ??

Comment: The Async Task belongs to a seperate class...the function PrintRes is in the MainActivity(the Async task sends JSON data to the printRes)...and calling the AsynTask : _new AsyncCaller().execute(data);_ is also present in the Mainactivity...

Answer (score 0):

if you're receiving a JSON array from the data source then you need to create a JSON array from the data you received instead of trying to turn the array into an object.

try creating a new JSON array like the following.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(ParsingData);
```

Your JSON array should now be created from the data you received and you can then use it like a normal JSON array.

Comment: I have an URL,can i just add ParsingData="<URL to beused to download the data>"

Comment: You need to get the content from the url and pass it into the JSON array.

Comment: If you look at the API you can see that the JSON Array constructor should take a string. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html The String should be the data you received.

Comment: Using HttpConnection ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to create a method that uses HttpConnection and then returns a class. For instance, call it get data and it will return a string `JSONArray jsonArray = jsonArray(getData());`

Comment: Thanks,let me try and get back to you

Comment: No problem. That should help also with any debugging you need to do and is part of encapsulation (small methods doing small jobs)

Answer (score 0):

There is a option for processing Json Array like this

```
String data="[{"billedret":0,"class":"com.enteleki.sfa.botree.RetailerSummary","ctgcode":"G00"....... your full json text}]";
JSONArray completeArray = new JSONArray(data);

for (int i=0;i<completeArray .length();i++){
     JSONObject finalEntry=(JSONObject) completeArray .get(i);
       // add your logic for read info from finalEntry jsonObjec.

 }
```

i hope it fits for you.

Comment: This is perfect,but this data is in a link,and i need to fetch the data from the URL,i have another class for downloading the data,thanks a lot for your help

Comment: so actually your problem is fetch data from URL....then you can accept ans  if it works and raise another question.. Thank you